# Java - calling this.function() from composition object

Tags: java, composition

I have function dodaj(); in JFrame, and in this JFrame i have JPanel.
To use Buttons from JPanel i am using ActionListener. But when someone click on button I wanna call function dodaj(); from JFrame.
If I have ActionLIstener in JFrame i can use this.dodaj();, but i have action listener on JPanel, with is composition od JFrame.
How could i call dodaj(); (JFrame function) from ActionListener with is on JPanel?

Thanks for reading it and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: First off, you can usually simply call the method without the `this.` part and usually it will work.

Comment: If i do it i see error: "Cannot find symbol in JPanel"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't mention it, but are your JFrame and JPanels both classes, and so your problem is that you want to call a method from one class in another class? If so, the key is to get a reference to the JFrame class and pass it into the JPanel class via a constructor or method parameter.

For example:

```
class MyFrame extends JFrame {
   private MyPanel myPanel;

   public MyFrame() {
      myPanel = new MyPanel(this);
   }

   public void frameMethod() {
      System.out.println("in JFrame's frameMethod");
   }

}

class MyPanel extends JPanel {
   private MyFrame myFrame;
   private JButton someButton = new JButton("Button");

   public MyPanel(final MyFrame myFrame) {
      this.myFrame = myFrame;

      someButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
         @Override
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            myFrame.frameMethod();
         }
      });
   }  
}
```

As an aside, I don't recommend extending JFrame or JPanel without good reason such as the need to override methods.

Comment: Why you do not recomend extending JFrame or JPanel?

Comment: @user13: because I believe in the design philosophy to avoid inheritance unless necessary. Over-used inheritance can lead to bad design decisions, and can lead to sneaky difficult to debug errors. For instance see what happens if you create a class that extends JPanel, if you give it two int variables, x, and y, and two public "getter" methods, `getX()` and `getY()` that return the values for x and y respectively. This bug had me sleepless for a few days.

Comment: Thanks one more time i used your code in my program and it works very well.

Answer (score 1):

In your JPanel, you can always refer back to your parent JFrame container by using getParent().

If your ActionListener on JPanel is an anonymous class, you can directly refer to it by using getParent() method directly. If your ActionListener is a separate class, you can pass the parent-reference to it when you instantiate it.